# Flutter pass email user parameter to another page after validate user in Google SignIn and Firebase

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, future, flutter

I tried using Firebase / Google SignIn, but... see what's happened? How to do it using Future / async function ? How to do the Scaffold wait the return of mostraUID() ? Could you show me the best way to implement it?

I'm not know use Future / async to pass a user email to another page before Widget build(BuildContext context) { }

It's works fine after I click on FAB.

I need receive email user to compose my Database Reference Firebase.

I'm a newbie in Flutter.

Is there any best way to perform this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

// Variável de controle de Autenticação Google
final googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

// Variável para gerenciar a Autenticação com o Google Firebase
final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


String _loggedUser = "INITIAL VALUE";
String _loggedUserTitle = "NEW TITLE";


void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    mostraUID();
  }



  Future<Null> mostraUID() async {

    print("Entrei na mostraUID");

    GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
    if(user == null)
      user = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
    if(user == null) {
      user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    }

    // O gerenciamento de TOKEN é implícito
    if(await auth.currentUser() == null) {
      GoogleSignInAuthentication credentials = await googleSignIn.currentUser.authentication;
      await auth.signInWithGoogle(
        idToken: credentials.idToken,
        accessToken: credentials.accessToken,
      );
    }

    _loggedUser = user.email;

    FirebaseUser userFirebase = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    print("User no Firebase: " + userFirebase.uid);
    print("User no GoogleSignIn: " + user.email);

  }




  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print("Entrei no Widget build(Build Context context)");

    setState(() {
      _loggedUserTitle = _loggedUser;
    });

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        //title: new Text(widget.title),

        // *************************************************************************************************** //
        // I'll use "message/$_loggedUser" to compose my database reference (Firebase) to show user's messages
        title: new Text(_loggedUserTitle),
        // *************************************************************************************************** //

      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text(
          'Button tapped $_counter time${ _counter == 1 ? '' : 's' }.',
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't use code snippets this way. Since you can't run it, it's irrevelant. Instead use `Code Sample`.

Answer (score 0):

That question is in fact an architectural problem.

Flutter is all about immutability, state management and composition. That's a quite complicated topic. So instead I'll link some good articles :

- https://hackernoon.com/why-native-app-developers-should-take-a-serious-look-at-flutter-e97361a1c073
- https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKXz3pUkw9A

Answer (score 0):

You need to deal with lots of state manipulations in Flutter and there are a lot of Design Patterns to deal with them. However, for your specific question; I would recommend you to follow [this](https://felangel.github.io/bloc/#/flutterfirebaselogintutorial?id=flutter-firebase-login-tutorial) tutorial which shows how to implement firebase and google login using BLOC pattern.